# Nested if statements...or use Switch Case?

Tags: switch-statement, swift3, nested-if

I have a large nested if.  One portion of the nested if works, however, in the second portion only some of the nested if works.  I cannot get the switch case to work.

```
//Match Scoring    //All work, when I flip Poker on top of Match the first and second ifs do not work
    if playerMatchCardsArray[0] == playerMatchCardsArray[1] &&
        playerMatchCardsArray[1] == playerMatchCardsArray[2]{

    } else if playerMatchCardsArray[0] == playerMatchCardsArray[1] ||
              playerMatchCardsArray[1] == playerMatchCardsArray[2] ||
              playerMatchCardsArray[0] == playerMatchCardsArray[2]{

    } else if playerMatchCardsArray[0] != playerMatchCardsArray[1] ||
              playerMatchCardsArray[1] != playerMatchCardsArray[2] ||
              playerMatchCardsArray[0] != playerMatchCardsArray[2] {

//Poker Scoring   //All work, when I flip Poker on top of Match.  However the following lines work do not work

    // SUITED THREE OF A KIND  //does not work
    if firstRandomNumber == secondRandomNumber && secondRandomNumber == thirdRandomNumber {

    // STRAIGHT FLUSH // works
} else if straightCardsArray[0] == 1 && straightCardsArray[1] == 2 &&  straightCardsArray[2] == 3 && 
       flushFirstRandomNumber == flushSecondRandomNumber &&
       flushFirstRandomNumber == flushThirdRandomNumber{

    // THREE OF A KIND  // does not work
 } else if pairFirstRandomNumber == pairSecondRandomNumber &&
       pairFirstRandomNumber == pairThirdRandomNumber {

    //STRAIGHT FORMULA // works
 } else if straightCardsArray[0] == 1 && straightCardsArray[1] == 2 &&  straightCardsArray[2] == 3 {

    // SUITED PAIR // does not work
 } else if firstRandomNumber == secondRandomNumber || 
       secondRandomNumber == thirdRandomNumber || 
       firstRandomNumber == thirdRandomNumber {

   // PAIR  // does not work
 } else if pairFirstRandomNumber == pairSecondRandomNumber ||
      pairFirstRandomNumber == pairThirdRandomNumber ||
      pairSecondRandomNumber == pairThirdRandomNumber {

    // FLUSH  // works
 } else if flushFirstRandomNumber == flushSecondRandomNumber &&
       flushFirstRandomNumber == flushThirdRandomNumber {
```

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.  It's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It was the '}' that was causing the issue.